# Explorer view showing incorrect dates for document library files

Tags: 2007, document-library, webdav, explorer-view

We have a bit of a weird problem, and I am baffled.

Incorrect dates in windows explorer:
We map N: drives to document libraries, by using the following command:

> net use n: "http://vle/staff/supportstaff/School Office"

For some reason the last modified date in windows explorer (not ie) is not showing correctly, can send screenshot on request, it wont allow me to attach is a dont have enough points?!.

The webview however of the document library does show a correct date. The document is XLS (2003 format, is that a problem?)

Comment: Please split your second problem into another question, you'll get more targeted responses.

Comment: Regarding question 1 - what time zone are you in?

Comment: Andy, we are GMT (London, UK)

Comment: What is the time difference between the correct date and incorrect one, is it 1 hour by chance?

Comment: Could you type in several pairs of expected vs. wrong dates you see?